# Virtual derived functions and include loops

Tags: c++, class, oop, types, virtual

I am currently learning C++ as a student and I have a problem.

Here is my problem :

- I have a class Point (described below)
- I have a class Cartesian and Polar whom inherit from Point

I need to create a function to convert a Cartesian to Polar and a Polar to Cartesian. It needs to be callable directly from Cartesian and Polar or by Point.

Here's roughly what I got right now (it doesn't compile) :

```cpp
// point.hpp
class Point {
    public:
        virtual void display(std::ostream&) const = 0;
        virtual void convert(Cartesian&) const = 0;
        virtual void convert(Polar&) const = 0;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Point&);
};

// cartesian.hpp
class Cartesian : public Point {
    private:
        double _x;
        double _y;
    
    public:
        Cartesian();
        Cartesian(const double, const double);
        void display(std::ostream&) const;
        void convert(Polar&) const override;
        void setX(const double);
        void setY(const double);
        double getX() const;
        double getY() const;
};

// polar.hpp
class Polar : public Point {
    private:
        double _a;
        double _d;
    
    public:
        Polar();
        Polar(const double, const double);
        void display(std::ostream&) const;
        void convert(Cartesian&) const override;
        void setAngle(const double);
        void setDistance(const double);
        double getAngle() const;
        double getDistance() const;
};
```

I know the design is crap but I can't change it.

Here's the unit tests to pass :

```cpp
TEST_CASE ( "TP1_Point::ConversionVersPolaire_V1" ) {
 const double x = 12.0;
 const double y = 24.0;
 const double a = 63.434948;
 const double d = 26.832815;

 const Cartesian c(x,y);
 Polar p;

 c.convert(p);

 REQUIRE ( p.getAngle() == Approx(a).epsilon(1e-3) );
 REQUIRE ( p.getDistance() == Approx(d).epsilon(1e-3) );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TEST_CASE ( "TP1_Point::ConversionVersCartesien_V1" ) {
 const double a = 12.0;
 const double d = 24.0;
 const double x = 23.475542;
 const double y = 4.9898805;

 const Polar p(a,d);
 Cartesian c;

 p.convert(c);

 REQUIRE ( c.getX() == Approx(x).epsilon(1e-3) );
 REQUIRE ( c.getY() == Approx(y).epsilon(1e-3) );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
TEST_CASE ( "TP1_Point::ConversionVirtuel" ) {
 const double x = 12.0;
 const double y = 24.0;
 const double a = 63.434948;
 const double d = 26.832815;

 Cartesian c(x,y);
 Polar p(a,d);

 const Point * x1 = &c;
 const Point * x2 = &p;

 Cartesian c1;
 Cartesian c2;
 Polar p1;
 Polar p2;

 x1->convert(c1);
 x1->convert(p1);
 x2->convert(c2);
 x2->convert(p2);

 REQUIRE ( c1.getX() == Approx(x).epsilon(1e-3) );
 REQUIRE ( c1.getY() == Approx(y).epsilon(1e-3) );
 REQUIRE ( c2.getX() == Approx(x).epsilon(1e-3) );
 REQUIRE ( c2.getY() == Approx(y).epsilon(1e-3) );

 REQUIRE ( p1.getAngle() == Approx(a).epsilon(1e-3) );
 REQUIRE ( p1.getDistance() == Approx(d).epsilon(1e-3) );
 REQUIRE ( p2.getAngle() == Approx(a).epsilon(1e-3) );
 REQUIRE ( p2.getDistance() == Approx(d).epsilon(1e-3) );
}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: What is the error message of the compiler? I think you need a forward declaration in the point class because it does not know about Polar and Cartesian or you have cyclic include. Can you also provide the include statements?

Comment: You need to override both conversion functions in both classes (one of them is going to be trivial).

Comment: Is your problem that you haven't seen cartesian and polar in maths class? Then it would be difficult to program the conversion. C++ has trigonometry functions that can help with the conversion in [cmath](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath)

Comment: ```error: cannot declare variable ‘p’ to be of abstract type ‘Polar’ Polar p;```
I used the elaborated type below.
The math convertion isn't the problem, it's the code structure that I can't figure out.

Comment: Probably that last error is followed by informational messages saying what pure virtual functions in `Polar` are missing an override.

Comment: ```c++
polaire.cpp.o: in function Cartesien::convertir(Polaire&) const:
polaire.cpp:(.text+0x100): multiple definition of Cartesien::convertir(Polaire&) const; cartesien.cpp.o:cartesien.cpp: first defined here
polaire.cpp.o: in function Polaire::convertir(Cartesien&) const:
polaire.cpp: multiple definition of Polaire::convertir(Cartesien&) const; cartesien.cpp.o:cartesien.cpp: first defined here
cartesien.cpp.o: undefined reference to Cartesien::convertir(Cartesien&) const
polaire.cpp.o: undefined reference to Polaire::convertir(Polaire&) const
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these declarations of member functions

```
    virtual void convert(Cartesian&) const = 0;
    virtual void convert(Polar&) const = 0;
```

the names Cartesian and Polar are not yet declared.

You need either to introduce them as forward declarations before the class Point like

```
class Cartesian;
class Polar;
```

or to use elaborated type names in the function declarations like

```
    virtual void convert( class Cartesian& ) const = 0;
    virtual void convert( class Polar& ) const = 0;
```

As the function display is also virtual you should use the keyword override in its declarations in derived classes.

```
    void display(std::ostream&) const override;
```

Also if one of the function convert is not overridden in one of the derived classes then the corresponding class will be still abstract.

Comment: I tried the elaborated type names and I override the ```convert()``` funtion in both Cartesian and Polar but it still doesn't compile : 
```error: cannot declare variable ‘p’ to be of abstract type ‘Polar’ Polar p;```
It's as if the elaborate class overwrite the main class if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Jairo You need to override the function display. That is all pure virtual functions  (and in the base class there are 3 pure virtual functions)  shall be overridden in each derived class.

Comment: It already is, I just ommitted it. All the unit test for the other functions pass. It just convert that poses a problem.

Comment: @Jairo  Before the class Polar you need to include the forward declaration of the class Cartesian. And vice versa in the header with the class definition Cartesian you need to include a forward declaration of the class Polar.

Comment: Ok, I fixed my code and now it works, I used the elaborated type names and completed the virtual redefinition.
Thank you all for your responses.